# How to use functools.singledispatch to create a class method outside of class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a class method in a different module from the original class. Can this be done using `singledispatch` and function overloading?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Where exactly did you stuck?

Comment: @ShadowsInRain Thanks, it is working now. I was unable to declare a class method outside of class. I have now made the method independent and instead pass the object of the class to the method.

Comment: You may also assign method to a class: `A.foo = foo`.